# Get URL parameter from LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to retrieve url parameters through a lightning web component(Using LWC Components in Visualforce Pages)

For exemple : wwww.my-salesforce.com/EnrollmentForm?EnrId=4487855adff78

How can i get the `EnrId` value in the LWC framework.

From visual force page i can get the paramter value like `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Paramtervalue}`. but not sure how to get the value in LWC.

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" /> 
<script>

var enrollIdVF = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.EnrId}";
$Lightning.use("c:EnrollVf", function() {  //Aura app name
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:enrollment_5",
                               {EnrId : enrollId},
                               "lightning",
                               function(cmp) {
                                   //  console.log("button was created");
                                   // do some stuff
                               }
                              );
});
</script>
```

JS:

```
@api EnrId
@wire(getParentdetails, { enrollmentName: this.EnrId })
```

How to read the `enrollIdVF` value in LWC components

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@api EnrId` in your lwc JS controller, you'll have an access to your vf page `enrollIdVF` field

Comment: Error in $A.getCallback() [TypeError: Cannot read property 'EnrId' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {ltng:outApp}

Comment: You need to include the code to allow people to help you when you see that sort of additional error; it means you did something wrong. Just stating the error really doesn't help.

Comment: Try to remove quotes from this part {"EnrId" : enrollIdVF }, like that:  {EnrId : enrollIdVF }

Comment: Edited My code, @Valentine Potapov still same error after removing the quote

Comment: hery try c_ EnrId and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

In addition to declaring a public property like `@api EnrId`, you will need to expose it in the meta file of your component.

Example for a component being used in a lightning record page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="EnrId" type="String" label="EnrIdD" description="Automatically bind the url parameter to the component variable" default="{!EnrId}"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

We Can pass `recordId` in directly instead of `EnrId`

```
$Lightning.createComponent("c:enrollment_5",
                       {recordId : enrollId},
                       "lightning",
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get parameters from URL is use **CurrentPageReference**.

`currentPageReference.state` allows you to get params.

Example:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {

    currentPageReference = null; 
    urlStateParameters = null;

    enrId = null;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
       if (currentPageReference) {
          this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
          this.setParametersBasedOnUrl();
       }
    }

    setParametersBasedOnUrl() {
       this.enrId = this.urlStateParameters.EnrId || null;
    }
}
```

More details you can find here
https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/get-url-parameters-in-lwc